# how to install command line programs

Tags: applications, installation, command-line

How to i install binaries on my non-rooted tablet i have the terminal application called [**Terminal IDE**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) and i followed the instructions, i put my compiled binary in the folder `local/bin/`. I comiled a C program using the appliaction called [**C4droid**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en) and then I exported the binary to the `/local/bin/` folder but when i tried to run the program it said permission denied.

what am i doing wrong? How do install binaries?

This is the program that I am trying to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/base64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what 'Access Denied' in this case is you do not have the correct permissions to execute the file. This can be solved 2 different ways:

1. use the `sudo` command (super user can run any file)

   > sudo myprogram -options param1 param2 param...
2. use `chmod o+x filename` to let anyone execute the file

so basically you need a rooted device to be able to run that file, unless you change the permissions of the file before you transfer it to the device. You can use the `chmod` command to add the execute permission to the file before you hand it off to the device. This way anyone can execute the file. Be warned, adding the execute permission for everyone is a security hole if the program can be used to change the file system in any way. Rooting your tablet in this case might actually be safer.

Comment: There is no `sudo` command

Comment: you need to root your tablet to get permission to use the `sudo` command.

Comment: But when i changed the permission of the file it ran just fine, the program is for encoding/decoding binary files in base64 so that i can easily send them using email.

Comment: ok great, I'm glad you got it running!

Comment: @John There is no `sudo` command on Android (common mistake for us Linuxers), one simply calls `su` here. However, `chmod` is the correct way here, nothing to do with `su`. What you most likely wanted instead, was `sh myprog param param` – the trick used to execute shell scripts even if they're located on an SDCard mounted with `noexec` ;)